# HTML5 Canvas expanding the draw area after drawing

Tags: jquery, canvas, chart.js

I have a query about HTML5 canvas and the possibility of adding additional drawing space after an item/s (a graph in this case) have been drawn already.

My graph and it's title take up the entire canvas as it stands using the library ChartJS (Ver 2.7.0) to generate it. However I want to take the current canvas element with graph drawn on it, add say... 100px above and below the already drawn content (effectively a header and footer) and then define a template of coordinates for adding several new text elements to the canvas. Ready to exported to a png.

**Current Export Function:**

```
 function exportWithFormatting($id) { 
    //get the charts variable name (stored as a data-attribute on the canvas element called chart-var)
    var chart_variable_name = $("#" + $id).data('chart-var');

    //convert this to a usable variable instead of a string
    var chart_variable = eval(chart_variable_name);

    //get canvas element using id passed in
    var ctx = $("#" + $id);

    //get data-export-title attribute (multiline title with Source, Title etc)
    var exportTitle = $(ctx).data('export-title');

    //get context
    context = ctx[0].getContext('2d');

    //get the old title from the ChartJS Object (ready to use for going back to old title)
    var old_title = chart_variable.options.title.text;
    chart_variable.options.title.text = "";

    // get the exportTitle as an array, this will allow for MultiLine titles on export
    arr = exportTitle.split(',');

    //push String "Title" + old_title variable so we have the title added at the end of the array
    arr.push(old_title);

    //set the charts title text to the new Multiline export title.
    chart_variable.options.title.text = arr;

    //run the update on the chart
    chart_variable.update(0);

    chart_variable = eval(chart_variable_name);

    //convert the chart to a base64 link PNG
    //var base64link = ($('#' + $id)[0]).toDataURL("image/png");

    var newBase64 = chart_variable.toBase64Image();
    //insert an <a> tag which is hidden, before the save button - irrelevant where it goes as it wont be seen but for consistency
    $("<a id='" + $id + "-button-temp' style='display:none;' class='button-style' href='" + newBase64 + "' download='" + $id + ".png' >Download</a>").insertAfter($('#' + $id + '-button'));

    chart_variable.options.title.text = "";

    //programmatically find and click the <a> tag to initiate the download of the image
    //($(document).find("#" + $id + "-button-temp")[0]).click();

    //programmatically remove the <a> tag so we dont clutter the page with unecessary HTML that is hidden
    //($(document).find("#" + $id + "-button-temp")[0]).remove();

    //set chart title back to previous title
    chart_variable.options.title.text = old_title;
}
```

Comment: This can be done, but I think it's easier to use the padding option that comes with ChartJS. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html

Comment: I think the problem with that is that it seems to squish my graph smaller and make it completely illegible

Comment: In my opinion it's easier to make the container bigger in the beginning so the graph won't squish even if you add the padding

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by saving the first canvas as a base64 string, with two variables for its width and height. Added 200px to the height and created a new canvas with the .png created from the base64 and placed on the new canvas offsetting its y coordinates by 100px.

Using the padding built in to chartJS only squashed my graphs height causing it to be illegible.